# Hubspot documentation does not have proper documentation for specific tech

Tags: laravel, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api

I tried to use the documentation indicated [here](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/companies), but unfortunately the example code is really difficult to follow.

#### For example:

[image]

The code from the image above returns `400` error. However, if I tried the one from the [repo](https://github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-php) it works. Like so:

```
$response = $hubspot->crm()->companies()->basicApi()->getPage();
```

The `toObjectType` does not have description on how to use it too. Maybe there is a separate documentation?

Any idea with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, don't get mad at me.

- Just go to https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/overview
- Go to **CRM** section then under `Objects >` click `Companies` (for my case it is for companies) on the left sidebar.
- Click the **Endpoints** tab.
- Click `Endpoints for this page` dropdown to select what endpoint do you need. For my case I selected `List` of companies under **Basic** type since there is 2 types of API which is the `Association` and the `Basic`.
- You will see an example code on the right side of the page.